# AWS node to node communication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, low-latency

On AWS, I would like one node in say London to interact with a node in say Hong Kong, do i have to build out a specialed multicast communication channel between these two nodes or does AWS have something internal that would allow for information to be sent back and forth.

Latency critical and throughput matters.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to set this up is by using [VPC Peering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html), you need to create one VPC in London, another VPC in Hong Kong and then establish a VPC peering between the two of them.

This will utilize [AWS Global Network](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/global_network/) to connect both VPCs, which has a really good performance and low latency, surely much better than using the public internet.

I recommend you go through the official AWS documentation on how to set-up a cross-region VPC Peering as they explain it much better than I could.

Comment: thank you so much. Any suggestions as to how i would go about it if it was say a 3 way multicast or n combinations?

Say Japan/Hong Kong/ London? and they needed to all communicate?  

I guess complexity is something I want to think about now as opposed to later when its hard to scale.

Comment: If you're looking into have multiple VPCs and they all communicate, take a look at Transit Gateway, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/building-scalable-secure-multi-vpc-network-infrastructure/transit-gateway.html

Comment: is something like Aeron necessary for AWS? Or can i circumvent that?

Comment: You shouldn't need any additional tools, AWS have a lot of services to support networking between VPC